# multi dimensional object

Tags: javascript

how can you make a multi dimensional object??

```
function tst(){
    this.a = function(){
        alert(this.b.abc.c());
    };

    this.b = function(){

    };
}
var obj = new tst();
obj.b.abc = function(){
    this.c = function(){
        return 'hello world';
    };
};

obj.a();
```

Comment: ... depends how you call the `abc` function ...

Comment: have edited my question.. what if you want to call it from itself?

Comment: @sime how can you call it then?

Comment: Btw, you have a typo in line two: `funciton`

Comment: And the alert() is not properly closed with `)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this code:

```
obj.b.abc = function(){
    this.c = function(){
        return 'hello world';
    };
};
```

Calling the `abc` function will *not* create a `obj.b.abc.c` function, but a `obj.b.c` function. Therefore, `this.b.abc.c()` throws an error because such a function doesn't exist.

---

This will make it work:

```
function tst() {
    this.a = function() {
        alert( this.b.abc.c() );
    };

    this.b = function() {

    };
}

var obj = new tst();

obj.b.abc = function() {
    this.abc.c = function() { // <--- NEW 
        return 'hello world';
    };
};

obj.b.abc(); // <--- NEW
obj.a();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vgpNU/

Comment: how can you avoid to write this.abc but instead this in the obj.b.abc method?

Comment: @clarkk You could use `arguments.callee` to reference `abc`: `arguments.callee.c = function() { ...`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vgpNU/1/ However, I'm not sure if using `arguments.callee` would be a good idea...

Comment: or is it bad practice to do so

Comment: I mean.. is it bad practice to create objects with more "dimensions"?

Comment: @clarkk No, of course not. Multiple levels are OK. It's the pattern that creates such objects that can be better or worse.

Comment: how would you create an object with more levels then? :)

Comment: @clarkk How many instances of such an object would you need? Do you need to be able to add new properties or levels to the object subsequently? Or is the full structure known from the beginning?

Comment: the full structure is known from the start

Comment: @clarkk Will there be only one object (a singleton), or do you need multiple instances that run in parallel?

Comment: @clarkk Also, have `a`, `b`, `abc`, and `c` to be functions? Do you need to call them? Or could they be regular objects?

Comment: it has to be only one object.. I need to call the methods/object a bit like in your last answer

Comment: arh.. of course.. I never thought about it like this var obj = {
    a: function() { alert(this.b.abc.c()); },
    b: function() {}
};

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine here:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/e3pfu/

```
function tst(){
    this.a = function(){

    };

    this.b = function(){

    };
}
var obj = new tst();
obj.b.abc = function(){
    alert(this);

    this.c = function(){

    };
};

obj.b.abc();
```